# what can a potential attacker do if he knows the column names in my database

Tags: javascript, php, security

I'm trying to send data from db to client with this code:

On server side:

```
$prep = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?");
$prep->execute([$_POST['id']]);
$user = $prep->fetch();
echo json_encode($user);
```

Client side

```
$.ajax({
   url : '/path/to/myaction',
   data : {id : id},
   complete : function(data){
       console.log(JSON.parse(data));
   }

});
```

The result is something like:

```
{id : 101,name : "Fudatura",birthdate : "1995/02/03",email : "fudatura@gmail.com"}
```

Everything is fine. I'm just a little worried about publishing the column structure. Is this a security problem? Do I need to worry about this?

Comment: You can encrypt this data before `echo json_encode`

Comment: why are you parsing json? you could just put dataType: 'json' to ajax call params and it will be parsed automaticaly. Actualy also without this param jquery should be able to recognize json and parse it by it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is: what can a potential attacker *do* if he knows the column names in your database?

...

Hopefully nothing. It's just arbitrary *names*. Who cares what those names are? That in itself still doesn't give anybody access to anything they shouldn't have access to.

Having said that, *if* you have a vulnerability in your application which does allow someone access to something he shouldn't have access to, e.g. an SQL injection vulnerability, knowing the database structure *can* speed things up in using that vulnerability for something really bad. But, just obfuscating your column names will *not* add any actual security, it may just slow an attacker down a little bit and force them to poke around in the dark just a little longer.

See [this very nice walkthrough](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) of an attack from the attacker's point of view to understand the possibilities.

The bottom line is: don't bother, it just makes it unnecessarily harder for yourself without actually adding any actual security. Your real vulnerabilities are elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. You've just helped me out of this stuff. I will also change my question title.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried, you can rename the fields with aliases and send only fields you need to javascript. Just remove * from your select and replace it with cols and aliases list.

Comment: DO I need to do it? If someone know my database structure, how are they gonna play with this infomation?

Comment: It depends. In general it will just ease up the usage of exploits in your system. It all depends on privileges you've give to the user you're using to connect to database. Usually if somebody find an exploit to your system, they'll be able to retrieve the structure by them self.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose your column structure then run a "for" loop for $user variable  before json_encode and make your custom column array.